# How to dump / copy a a variable as code via IntellJ debugger?

Tags: scala, debugging, intellij-idea, copy-paste

I have a scala project and I use debugger through IntellJ a lot.

Sometimes, esp. when writing unit test I take the easy route of implementing some logic and writing the expected object later.

Basically I do:

```
 assert({} == actualValue)
```

I then at some point want to debug to that point and copy paste the value of `actualValue` via:

[image: Copy value from intellJ IDE through the debugger]

so that I can insert it like this:

```
 val expected = FinishedRun(
  id = "20180213165959sCdJr",
  createdAt = "2018-02-13T16:59:59.570+0000",
  finishedAt = "2018-02-13T17:00:18.118+0000"
)
```

Yet this is what I actually paste:

```
 FinishedRun(20180213165959sCdJr,Tue Feb 13 17:59:59 CET 2018,Tue Feb 13 18:00:18 CET 2018)
```

I then have to adapt the values again and I want to avoid that. Is there a way I can either dump the case class or copy it as code?

---

For completeness sake, this is the example case class with its companion object. The answer should apply to any object / variable:

```
case class FinishedRun
(
  id: String,
  createdAt: Date,
  finishedAt: Date
)

object FinishedRun {

  def apply(id: String,
            createdAt: String,
            finishedAt: String
           ): FinishedRun = {

    new FinishedRun(id, createdAt = parseDate(createdAt), finishedAt = parseDate(finishedAt))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to define custom type rendered in [Java Type Renderers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugger-data-type-renderers.html) settings (or from the variable context menu) and create the rendering for value of this type you need:
[image]
[image]